# Can't open python.exe in Windows Powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, path, exe

I've had my python program removed from windows a while ago, and recently downloaded python2.7.4 from the main site, but when I type "python" in the Windows PowerShell(x86) prompt from C:, I get the message "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.", and I'd like to find out how to fix this.

I get the same message when I'm in the actual python27 folder (and the `python.exe` is indeed there). However, when I type in `.\python`, it runs as expected, and my computer can run other `.exe`'s just fine. I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1 on a Sony VAIO laptop. I'm not very familiar with the inner workings of my computer, so I'm not sure where to look from here.

My current path looks like this, with the python folder at the very end:

`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\AGL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.42;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\AGL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.42;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin;C:\Python27`

Comment: couple of "silly" recommendations - have a `;` at the end of the path, and log out and log back in.

Answer (score 1):

Making the comments an answer for future reference:

Have a `;` at the end of the PATH and logout and log back in.